# how to generate a sequence based on the value of a column

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, relational-database

I have a table with messages sent by visitors of a website. I want to be able to group those messages if the visitor sent more than one message. By "group those messages" I mean displaying the messages grouped on the web page and not grouped in terms of relational logic. 
I want something like this:

```
s   email           messageid     
1 user1@mail.com     1     
1 user1@mail.com     3    
1 user1@mail.com     143    
2 user2@mail.com     343   
2 user2@mail.com      3   
3 user3@mail.com      3
```

As you can see the "s" column has the same number if the email is the same.

I have tried:

```
select ROW_NUMBER()  over(partition by m.email order by   m.email ) as s
```

I get this:

```
s   email           messageid     
1 user1@mail.com     1     
2 user1@mail.com     3    
3 user1@mail.com     143    
1 user2@mail.com     343   
2 user2@mail.com      3   
1 user3@mail.com      3
```

A sequence for each email is calculated.

Comment: `... ORDER BY [s]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `s` is the new column? You can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions) window function:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.email) as [s],
       t.email,t.messageid
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: too fast for me. However, it should be `DENSE_RANK` if you want consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Diego Alves Marking answer as accepted is the biggest thanks for who helped you. So click the tick mark.